# What is the difference between adding a method() as the last statement in a update and using LateUpdate()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't understand the use case of the `LateUpdate()` here. If the `LateUpdate()` is called after the `Update()`, then what is the difference the below two set of codes:

**First set of code**

```
void Update(){
    <some code>
    <further code>
    a();
}
 
void a(){
    <some code for a>
}
```

**Second set of code**

```
void Update(){
    <some code>
    <further code>
}
 
void LateUpdate(){
    <some code for a>
}
```

Are both the codes above same or is there any difference/ benefits on using the `LateUpdate()` instead of just calling a method as the last statement of the `update()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LateUpdate is called after *all* Update functions have been called. So if you have 15 Scripts with an Update function, and one with LateUpdate -- LateUpdate in that one script won't execute until the other 15 Updates have been called. So the difference between your two examples is that in the first one, `a()` is run right away as part of that Update invocation. In the second, `<some code for a>` won't run until every script with an Update function has run.

Reference
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html